# How to redirect output of a 'xterm -hold -e' command

Tags: bash, terminal, io-redirection, xterm, tee

I know you can use `tee` to log output from a command in a terminal, e.g.:

`df -h | tee ~/log.txt`

However, how can I do this with a more complex command like this:

`xterm -hold -e program arg1 arg2 arg3`

I tried this to no avail:

`xterm -hold -e matlab -noxterm -nojvm -r "solver('/path/to/a/folder',1)" | tee ~/log.txt`

My goal is to log all output of the `xterm` and **not** of the original terminal. The

Comment: so you're trying to get output of matlab ?

Comment: I am running MATLAB from the command line in a xterm (not using the GUI). Because my MATLAB code has a bug and is crashing quite severely I want to log everything that is shown in xterm to start debugging.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn on xterm logging and send all xterm output to a file:

`xterm -l -lf logfile.txt -e program`

Comment: sure - but not everyone has logging configured in xterm, and since OP didn't mention it, must assume it's not in OP's xterm.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting output can change the behavior of programs that run in a terminal.  If you want to capture *all* output of the program use something that does not interfere with the program, e.g., `script`:

```
xterm -hold -e script -c "program arguments" output.log
```

(Linux) or

```
xterm -hold -e script output.log program arguments
```

(OSX, other BSD)

Alternatively, you could setup `xterm` to write its screen to a "printer", e.g., using the `printerCommand` resource, or using the menu entry *Print-All Immediately*.

Further reading:

- [script(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) Linux
- [script(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html) OSX, etc.
- [xterm - terminal emulator for X](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output of the program that you tell xterm to run,  `xterm -hold -e " program arg1 arg2 arg3 | tee ~/log.txt"`

So for instance , in my Ubuntu I'd run from `gnome-terminal` something like `xterm -hold -e " firefox | tee ~/log.txt"`

There's also an option to log errors with

`xterm -hold -e program 2> errors.txt` which redirects any errors that usually go to console, to file

But this is a bit redundant, i think. Running a program from one terminal into another.